# How to insert image in reactjs using mutler

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

in this code i got an errror says throw new sequelizeError.ValidationError(null, this.errors) in this code i want to send a image from my backend to the database using the multer library

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Admin } = require("../models");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./Image",
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        return cb(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
        if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG)$/)) {
            req.fileValidationError = "Only the image file is allowed";
            return cb(new Error("Only the image file is allowed"), false);
        }
        cb(null, true);
    },
});

router.post("/", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
    const { 
            image,
            username, 
            password,
        } = req.body;
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash) => {
        Admin.create({
            image: image,
            username: username,
            password: hash,
        });
        res.json("Success");
    });
});

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {username, password} = req.body;

        const user = await Admin.findOne({where: {username: username}});

        if (!user) return res.json({error: "Admin User doesn't exist"});

        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((match) => {
            if(!match) return res.json({error: "Username and password is incorrect"});
            res.json("Login Success");
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error authentication the prompt", err);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

in that code i always get a success message from postman API but when i go and check my code  and my server will give an error says

```
throw new sequelizeError.ValidationError(null, this.errors);
            ^

ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: notNull Violation: Please enter image
    at InstanceValidator._validate (D:\My Portfolio\React Js\Admin\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:50:13)
    at async InstanceValidator._validateAndRunHooks (D:\My Portfolio\React Js\Admin\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:60:7)
    at async InstanceValidator.validate (D:\My Portfolio\React Js\Admin\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\instance-validator.js:54:12)
    at async model.save (D:\My Portfolio\React Js\Admin\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2368:7)
    at async Function.create (D:\My Portfolio\React Js\Admin\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1344:12) {
  errors: [
    ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'Please enter image',
      type: 'notNull Violation',
      path: 'image',
      value: null,
      origin: 'CORE',
      instance: Admin {
        dataValues: {
          id: null,
          image: undefined,
          username: 'Rameljay',
          password: '$2b$10$a9ltyD7176rTQ33sKtpiuea8xS.SBz/FV0423XRa6dUAGGOXST0Fm',
          updatedAt: 2022-11-28T23:47:08.298Z,
          createdAt: 2022-11-28T23:47:08.298Z
        },
        _previousDataValues: {
          username: undefined,
          password: undefined
        },
        uniqno: 1,
        _changed: Set(9) {
          'username',
          'password'
        },
        _options: {
          isNewRecord: true,
          _schema: null,
          _schemaDelimiter: '',
}
```

In this code below this is the code for my reactjs and also i am using Formik,Yup and Axios library

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import axios from 'axios';

const initialValues = {
        image: "",
        username: "",
        password: "",
    };

 const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        image: Yup.mixed().required("You need to provide a file"),
        username: Yup.string().min(3).max(20).required(),
        password: Yup.string().min(2).max(20).required(),
    });

   const onSubmit = (data) => {
        axios.post("http://localhost:3001/auth", data).then(() => {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };

<Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
 >
<Form>
<label>Image</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="image" component="span"/>
                    <input
                        autoComplete="off"
                        id="image"
                        name="file"
                        type="file"
                        onChange={(e) => {this.image("image", e.target.files[0])}}
                    />
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="username" component="span" />
                    <Field
                        autoComplete="off"
                        id="username"
                        name="username"
                        placeholder="Ex. guko"
                    />
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <ErrorMessage name="password" component="span" />
                    <Field
                        autoComplete="off"
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="Ex. guko1234"
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</From>
</Formik>
```

that is my exact error can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please add your react code too? It will help us understand how you are sending your image

Comment: i just edited to see my reactjs frontend code

Comment: Did you check the form data you are sending to your backend? is the image sending to the backend correctly?

Comment: in my backend I use postman and all the data but in the image is undefined

Comment: Can you log the data that you get from your form? I think you don't receive your image there.

Comment: yes that is my 100% problem into my code. I do not receive any image into my code can you help me with that?

Comment: yes, why not. I suggest you control the input by the state not the variables within the Fields element. By that, I mean set state whenever there was a change, you have to pass the state values to fields. then change the button type from submit to button and create an Onclick function. then you have to create a [form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object. After that send that and make a request to your back end.It should work

Comment: as of now. i can now store the image into my database using postman. but now my problem is how can i hook image into my frontend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250005/discussion-between-farbod-shabani-and-ramel-jay-cuna).